# iOS - Incompatible block pointer types in AFNetworking GET method

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, afnetworking

I'm learning to use `AFNetworking` and do a GET request.

`AFNetworking (3.1.0)`

`XCode 6`

Code:

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"http://localhost:5000/index" parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error)p;
    }];
```

However, I got the error

> Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSURLSessionTask *__strong, NSError *__strong)' to parameter of type 'void (^ __nullable)(NSURLSessionDataTask * __nonnull __strong)'

Tried many times but couldn't figure out why?

Comment: Look at the failure block. What are the parameters supposed to be? What are you using? See the difference? The error is showing the difference. They are similar but different.

Comment: What if I want to get the html page? What should the parameters be?

Comment: Just now I checked the document. Doesn't `Xcode 6` support `AFNetworking 3.0+`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I find out that the problem really is the wrong version `Xcode`. In `Xcode 6` it doesn't recognize `nullable`. Upgrading my `Xcode` just solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i think your parameter value don't send nil values, I am also using afNetworking Get method, please refer below code,

viewDidLoad give below code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:5000/index"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    //AFNetworking asynchronous url request
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        movies = [responseObject objectForKey:@"enquiry"];

        NSSortDescriptor *titleSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"FirstName"
                                                                  ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
//        NSMutableArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: titleSort, nil];
        movies=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[movies sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[titleSort]]];

        NSLog(@"The Array: %@",movies);
        [self.mytableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);

    }];

    [operation start];
```

don't forget `#import "AFNetworking.h"` in header
hope its helpful